# ngFor not working correctly with ngModel (angular 5.1.2)

Tags: angular, angular5

I am seeing strange behaviour with ngFor in combination with ngModel. Here's an example:

```
heroes = [
   {
      "name": "Deadpool"
   },
   {
      "name": "Thor"
   },
   {
      "name": "Superman"
   },
   {
      "name": "Batman"
   }
];
```

With the following code:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input">
      <label>Superhero</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" name="hero">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

Superhero: Batman
Superhero: Batman
Superhero: Batman
Superhero: Batman

Whereas if I don't use ngModel, but just print the value instead, it works correctly:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input">
      <label>Superhero</label>
      <span>{{hero.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

Superhero: Deadpool
Superhero: Thor
Superhero: Superman
Superhero: Batman

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you setup demo on stackblitz? I tried it and i see the same result

Comment: Both work for me

Comment: Checked your code in StackBlitz, works exactly as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awzcbm?file=app/chips-input-example.ts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only issue here is input same `input` `name` :

change `name="hero"` to `name="hero{{i}}"`

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes;let i = index;">
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" name="hero{{i}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this did fix the problem.

Comment: @Spacejockey , Glad to know , Happy Coding :)

Comment: why name value was added `{{i}}` ? @Spacejockey

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing much wrong. Let me show you how to fix, step by step:

1) Use single quotes ' and not double quotes " in your heroes array, it should be like this:

```
heroes = [
    {
       'name': 'Deadpool'
    },
    {
       'name': 'Thor'
    },
    {
       'name': 'Superman'
    },
    {
       'name': 'Batman'
    }
 ];
```

2) To just show the values in an input field you can use:

value="{{hero.name}}" OR [value]="hero.name" and same goes with name
like this:

```
<input value="{{hero.name}}" name="{{hero.name}}">
<input [value]="hero.name" [name]="hero">
```

3) For using ngModel you need to have FormsModule in your imports array in app.module.ts and import import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
like this:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
]
```

Now two way data binding would work:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="input">
        <label>Superhero</label>
        // Just show value in input
        <input value="{{hero.name}}" name="{{hero.name}}">
        // Another way to Just show value in input
        <input [value]="hero.name" [name]="hero.name">
        // This is our boy who make two way data binding easy
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" [name]="hero.name">
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks